# Can't I use two different condition at "on" in a join?

Tags: linq, join

Tried this :

```
myStructs = from MyObject s in MyObjects
            join c in Categories on s.CategoryID equals c.Item1 && s.Stars equals c.Item2
            select s;
```

but seems I can't wrote 2 condition at the join? Where am I wrong? On SQL this can be done as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an anonymous type to join on multiple conditions/fields:

```
myStructs = from s in MyObjects
            join c in Categories 
            on new { s.CategoryID, s.Stars }  equals new { CategoryID = c.Item1, Stars = c.Item2 }
            select s;
```

Comment: It said "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect'"

Comment: @markzzz: Edited my answer, you need to use the same names in the anonymous types.